How do I use langchains retry and output-fixing parser with the json parser?

I tried using it in a custom chain like the example on langchains website, but the error that I get even when I try using the output-fixing parser is this.
pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Generation
text
str type expected (type=type_error.str)

The workaround provided in this issue can work for your case while langchain is not updated since it's probably a bug.
